# How to say this is Korean

Tags: honorific, formal

It is a formal letter:

This is to certify that according to the records of the National population register, the marital status of the above-named person is reflected as SINGLE and is free to enter into marriage in any country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation suggestion:

이 서류는 위 사람의 혼인 상태가 국가인구기록부에 독신으로 기록되어 있으며 어느 국가에서든 자유롭게 혼인할 수 있다는 것을 증명합니다.